# Jetpack Compose navigation animation overlap

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, jetpack-compose-accompanist, jetpack-compose-animation

I am using accompanist navigation animation library.

framework versions:

```
    compose version = '1.1.1'
    accompanist version = '0.23.1'
```

The problem when we going back:

[image]

My current animations:

```
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Up,
                animationSpec = tween(navAnimationDuration)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            // this is sort of hack. We basically delaying eny actions.
            fadeOut(
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 1,
                    delayMillis = navAnimationDuration
                )
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
            fadeIn(
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 1,
                    delayMillis = navAnimationDuration
                )
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Down,
                animationSpec = tween(navAnimationDuration)
            )
        },
```

Is there anything that can be done here?